# Performing migrations with multiple databases in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have 2 databases in my Projects with multiple apps. All apps except for one are using default db, the other one has a separate db. After I ran makemigrations and ./manage.py migrate --database=separate_db_name I still have unapplied migration pending for default database.

The question is how can I make this migration only visible for my separate app and not others(that use default db). Thanks

Here is my router

```
class S3DatabaseRouter(object):
"""
Determine how to route calls for s3web_upload_dev database
"""

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read s3web_upload models to go to s3web_upload_dev
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 's3web_upload':
        return 's3web_upload_dev'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write s3web_upload models to go to s3web_upload_dev
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 's3web_upload':
        return 's3web_upload_dev'
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the s3web_upload app only appears in the 's3web_upload_dev' database
    """
    if app_label == 's3web_upload':
        return db == 's3web_upload_dev'
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

For the app that uses default db also need to be routed in the router class, Try the following code it should work.

```
class S3DatabaseRouter(object):
    """
Determine how to route calls for s3web_upload_dev database
"""
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read s3web_upload models to go to s3web_upload_dev
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 's3web_upload':
        return 's3web_upload_dev'
    if app_label == 'default': # if you using custome applable use it instead of 'default'
        return 'default' # it should be the db name from settings file
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write s3web_upload models to go to s3web_upload_dev
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 's3web_upload':
        return 's3web_upload_dev'
    if app_label == 'default':
        return 'default'
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the s3web_upload app only appears in the 's3web_upload_dev' database
    """
    if app_label == 's3web_upload':
        return db == 's3web_upload_dev'

    if app_label == 'default':
        return db == 'default'
    return None
```